# Can I change a Windows Enterprise 10 (Volume License) to Windows 10 Pro (OEM)?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

My Dell laptop came with Windows 7 Pro OEM label.

I have installed Windows 10 Enterprise edition (Volume License).

As Microsoft provides Windows 10 Pro for Windows 7 Pro OEM. I wanted to have Windows 10 Pro now as my laptop has Windows 7 OEM key.

Is there a work around to change the existing Windows 10 Enterprise edition (Volume License) to Windows 10 Pro (OEM).

Comment: Have you found answer? Need to know too :)